# Fiddler - Detect if data was GZipped

Tags: fiddler

Using Fiddler2, how can I detect if the response stream was in fact GZipped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Fiddler, simply click the **Inspectors** tab, then click the **Transformer** response inspector. It will tell you exactly what encodings have been applied.

Be sure that the "AutoDecode" option isn't checked in the Fiddler toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special magic marker that denotes a gzipped archive, the first two bytes, namely 0x1f and 0x8b tells it is a gzip archive. The RFC 1952 will give more information on this.

You can find out more by checking [wotsit](http://www.wotsit.org) and also on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip).